# Saving results output to SQL database table

Tags: powershell

Successfully generated the results from PowerShell, but don't know how to save this to a SQL database table ... as we need info in table for further manipulation.

```
Get-Content "D:\Files\Legal.doc"
| Select-String -Pattern  "Currency term loan in an aggregate amount equal to the"
| Select-Object Path, LineNumber, Line
| Export-Csv -Path D:\Results.csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding ASCII
```

Need help for saving about results in SQL table.

Comment: FTR, the code you posted can't possibly work. Am I correct to assume that you actually have all of that in one line, and just wrapped it for this question?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this approach...

```
$database = 'DBName'
$server = '.'
$table = 'DBTableName'

Import-CSV .\yourcsv.csv | ForEach-Object {Invoke-Sqlcmd `
-Database $database -ServerInstance $server `
-Query "insert into $table VALUES ('$($_.Column1)','$($_.Column2)')"
}
```

... as discussed below.

> [Storing Results from Powershell to SQL Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43324189/storing-results-from-powershell-to-sql-table)
>
> [How to import data from .csv in SQL Server using PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29539179/how-to-import-data-from-csv-in-sql-server-using-powershell)

So, this post could be considered a duplicate of the above.

Answer (score 1):

While @postanote's answer will work, be aware that it's susceptible to SQL injection errors or compromise because it's concatenating strings, and any of your values which contain a `'` will break it.

I recommend using [`Out-DbaDataTable`](https://dbatools.io/functions/out-dbadatatable/) and [`Write-DbaDataTable`](https://dbatools.io/functions/write-dbadatatable/) from [dbatools](https://dbatools.io/).

```
$database = 'DBName'
$server = '.'
$table = 'DBTableName'

Import-CSV .\yourcsv.csv | out-dbadatatable | write-dbadatatable -sqlinstance $server -table $table -database $database;
```

This should also run much faster than individual `INSERT` statements.